# Sesión PHP se pierde/borra en media hora

Tags: php, session

compañeros! Voy al grano:

**CONTEXTO**

1. Estoy trabajando en un proyecto PHP (crudo, sin frameworks) en el que hago uso de sesiones.
   Este proyecto se compone de 2 archivos: un index.php y un
   process.php. El 1ro es aquel que contiene el HTML, y el 2do contiene
   todas las funcionalidades PHP que se llaman al ejecutar AJAX. Eso es
   todo, no hay nada más.
2. Como se ve, nunca cambio de página, todo se visualiza dentro del index.php.
3. El proyecto está hosteado en el plan más económico de hosting compartido de Godaddy

**PROBLEMA** Me logueo correctamente a index.php, con lo cual se crea esta variable de sesión: *$_SESSION['usuario_id'] = 5;* (donde 5 es el ID del usuario actual). El problema radica en que si después de una media hora (aprox) de no hacer nada dentro del sistema, me animo a hacer algo, por ejemplo una petición a la base de datos, el sistema me indica que ya no existe la variable de sesión que se creó inicialmente al loguearme:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['usuario_id'])) {
    // Hago una consulta a la BD
}
else {
    echo 'La sesión ha expirado.'; // El sistema me muestra este mensaje después de media hora de inactividad
}
```

**QUÉ ESTOY HACIENDO PARA SOLUCIONAR EL PROBLEMA** Dos cosas:

1) Puse un .htaccess en la carpeta raíz del proyecto, que contiene esto:

```
php_value session.cache_expire 600
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 36000
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 36000
```

Como se ve [en esta captura](http:////d26lpennugtm8s.cloudfront.net/stores/364/576/rte/phpinfo.jpg), los ajustes sí surten efecto.

2) Por si acaso, y a modo de refuerzo, pongo lo siguiente al principio del index.php y del process.php

```
ini_set('session.cache_expire', 600);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 36000);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',36000);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
header('Expires: Sat, 29 Jun 2019 00:00:00 GMT'); // Aquí estoy poniendo una fecha 2 meses después del día de hoy
session_cache_expire(600);
session_set_cookie_params(36000);
session_start();
```

**RESULTADO** Nada funciona, todo sigue igual: si después de media hora de inactividad intento utilizar el sistema, éste me dice que no existe $_SESSION['usuario_id'].

**PREGUNTAS**

1. ¿Qué cosa está haciendo que mi variable de sesión se pierda/borre?
2. ¿Qué debo hacer para solucionar este problema?

**AÑADO MÁS INFORMACIÓN**
Uso Chrome como navegador. Entre a la configuración del navegador para buscar la cookie de sesión, y la encontré. revisé la fecha de expiración y como verán en [esta captura de pantalla](http://d26lpennugtm8s.cloudfront.net/stores/364/576/rte/cookie.jpg), la cookie de sesión debería expirar sólo hasta que se cierre el navegador. ¡Pero esto no ocurre! ¿Qué está pasando?

Saludos!

Comment: En php.ini puede modificar estos parámetros `session.cookie_lifetime 7200
session.gc_maxlifetime 7200`, de hecho tiene establecido que caduque cada 24 minutos si no se hace una acción en el navegador, espero alguien te puede ayudar, yo intenté poniendo todos esos métodos y ninguno me funcionó, o puedes utilizar `Localstorage` de Javascript.

Comment: @VickMuñoz, gracias. Supongo que te refieres a agregar un php.ini custom en la raíz del proyecto, porque claramente en un servidor compartido no tengo acceso al php.ini del servidor. No lo he intentado. Pero como decía arriba, sí logro cambiar el valor de **session.cookie_lifetime** a 36000, y un phpinfo() lo demuestra. Pero no surte efecto en mis scripts. Estoy seguro que hay solución incluso en un servidor compartido, porque si por ejemplo instalo Joomla, éste funciona bien y no se anda deslogueando. Ojalá alguien pueda ayudar a resolver este embrollo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Me respondo a mí mismo.

Claramente no podía dejar este tema sin solución por mucho tiempo, ya que el proyecto es laboral y urgía respuesta.

Al final no pude lograr que las variables de sesión duraran más de 24 minutos, ni armando el .htaccess, ni armando un php.ini en la raíz del proyecto, ni poniendo cabeceras en los PHP que modificaran la configuración de la duración del tiempo de vida de la sesión..., nada funcionó.

Puesto que hay librerías para todo, busqué y encontré varias. La primera que probé fue la de [Josantonius](https://github.com/Josantonius/PHP-Session), y el resultado fue el mismo, las sesiones seguían durando 24 minutos.

**Solución.** Hasta que me encontré con la librería [Zebra Session](https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Session), que resultó funcionar perfectamente. Funciona porque los datos de la sesión ya no se guardan en cookies, sino en una base de datos MySQL. Y el uso de esta librería es increíblemente sencillo: sólo se instancia un objeto de su clase y se acabó, las variables de sesión se usan tal como se usan normalmente.

Comment: Me gustaria mas detalles de como utilizaste las clases realice todo pero me genera nada

Answer (score -2):

mi respuesta anterior estaba poco detallada, detallo como logre hacerlo,
antes que todo debes crear una tabla session_data en tu db para q se guarden las variables session con su tiempo de duracion, luego modificar el valor de $session_lifetime = 28800, yo lo puse a 8 horas.en el constructor de ZebraSession

1ero - Debes guardar en una variable el link a tu db,
yo uso Singleton en mi clase conectar asi que solo tengo q invocarla y obtener la variable link

```
$this->_link = mysqli_connect($this->_host, $this->_user, $this->_pass, $this->_db) 
or die('Could not connect to database!'); //esto esta en mi clase Conectar.
```

2do  debes instanciar la clase session en todas tus paginas y al definir valor de session hacerlo normalmente, solo se invoca la clase y listo
aqui yo defino las variables cuando alguien se logea.

```
    <?
        require '../tools/Zebra_Session.php';
        require_once '../models/Conectar.php';
        $conectar = Conectar::getInstancia(); //invoco la clase 
        $link = $conectar->getLink(); //llamo a link de mi clase y guardo los datos de conexion  - mysqli
        try {
            $zebra = new Zebra_Session($link, 'sEcUr1tY_c0dE'); //inicio la clase ZebraSession
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e;
        }
        //.... codigo aqui ....

//defino los valores de session
    //automaticamente la clase llama a session_start no debemos llamarlos, establecemos las variables en session como siempre, la clase se encarga de guardarlo en la db
        $_SESSION["usuario"] = $usuario->getIdUsuario();
        $_SESSION["empresa"] = $usuario->getIdEmpresa();
        $_SESSION["ruc_empresa"] = $empresa->getRuc();
        $_SESSION["nombre_empresa"] = $empresa->getRazon();
        $_SESSION["empleado"] = $usuario->getDato();
        ?>
```

3ro en las paginas donde queemos usar la session invocamos al link y  a la clase ZebraSession. automaticamente se restauran las sessiones con sus valores. Aqui tengo un validador para las demas paginas

```
    <?php
    require '../tools/Zebra_Session.php';
    require_once '../models/Conectar.php';
    $conectar = Conectar::getInstancia();
    $link = $conectar->getLink();
    try {
        $zebra = new Zebra_Session($link, 'sEcUr1tY_c0dE');
        if (!isset($_SESSION["usuario"])) { //yo le puse como validacion cuando se pierda la session despues de 8 horas o ingresen directamente a la pagina sin logearse
            $zebra->stop(); //esto destruye todas las sessiones 
            header("location:login.php"); // redirecciona al login
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e;
    }

// .... continuar y trabajoas codigo 
//recuperas de session
$mivariable =  $_SESSION["empresa"]; 
//acuerdate de no llamar a session_start, lo primero q tienes q hacer es invocar a la clase Zebra.
```

git: https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Session

Comment: te estaria faltando darle una descripcion a la respuesta. solo codigo es dificil de entender para el usuario o alguien que busque el mismo problema.

Comment: Sólo veo código sin ninguna explicación. ¿Cómo es que tu respuesta resuelve la pregunta?

Comment: ya modifique la respuesta